# WifiManager and WiFi functionally

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I’m considering using `wifiManager` mostly to have the ability not to hard code WiFi creditntials. 
But In my current code I use WiFi’s functions as `WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true)` and `WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED`

How can it be done using `WifiManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. WifiManager does all that for you. You don't need anything like that in your code. Just follow the examples and read the documentation.

But if you do want to then you just need to remember that WifiManager is merely a library that configures the WiFi for you. If you want to query or alter the WiFi settings you can - exactly as you are right now. The two aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: I didn’t find any example to check if connected

Comment: You don't "check if connected". It connects, or it gives you an AP with a portal. In the latter case it blocks waiting for you to configure it. There is no "check". If your code runs then it's connected. All the examples show that.

Comment: I understand what you say, but from time to time there are disconnections, and I do not want that it will automatically go to AP mode. how many retires before entering AP mode/ time to try to reconnect ?

Comment: `WifiManager` is just a library that use the `WiFi` object. It's not a replacement. If you want to also interact with `WiFi` there's nothing to stop you. You can set auto reconnect. You can query the status. Just as you are.

Comment: OK. Should I define an instance of `Wifi` as well ?

Comment: No, there already is one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example that's on my Wemos D1 Mini. It stands up an AP until you provide credentials for your local LAN, then displays it's DHCP IP address on a 16x2 LCD and stands up a webserver. Once the credentials are stored it won't stand up the AP, it will just reconnect and do the main loop() of the sketch. To force the AP to restart you need to call the `ESP.reset();` method to flush the stored credentials and reboot the Wemos.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <Wire.h>

WiFiClient wemosCL;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

const int led = LED_BUILTIN;

LiquidCrystal_PCF8574 lcd(0x38);

void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  server.send(200, "text/html", "<html><head><title>ESP8266 Demo</title><style>body{background-color: #cccccc; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; Color: #000088;}</style></head><body><h1>Hello from ESP8266!</h1><p>IP Addr: " +
          WiFi.localIP().toString() + "<p></body></html>");

  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void handleNotFound() {
  digitalWrite(led, 1);
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += server.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (server.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += server.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < server.args(); i++) {
    message += " " + server.argName(i) + ": " + server.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  server.send(404, "text/plain", message);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
}

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  wifiManager.autoConnect("Wemos", "configuration");
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);

  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setBacklight(255);
  lcd.print("I'm alive");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print(".");
  }

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Status:Connected");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("IP:");
  lcd.print(WiFi.localIP());

  server.on("/", handleRoot);

  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);

  server.begin();
}

void loop(void) {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: Hi Dougi, something I miss is, when line of code reaches `wifimanager` in `setup` it only look for stored crediatials ? from what I understood in Mejenko's asnwer, once it passed that line, wifi is connected, so I don't understand why the section called `\\wait for connection` is relevant. I'm guessing that something I don't understand here :)

Comment: The `wait for connection` is after the credentials for my home WiFi are entered as it switches from `AP` to `STA` mode then my router does the DHCP handshake. That takes some time to run.

Comment: OK. and at next boot... when credentials were entered boot before, and just being used at current boot ... still when reaching `\\ wait for connection`- in that excat moment, is Wifi connected ?